# Vararg (`...`) function parameters don't work with `arg` variable

Tags: lua, arguments, torch

For lua, according to this tutorial, triple dots of a function can be accessed by a hidden variable named arg.

https://www.lua.org/pil/5.2.html

I write a very simple program

```
require 'torch'
function triDot(...)
    print('in triDot now')
    print(arg)
    for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
        print('i is',i,'v is',v)
    end
end
triDot('name1','name2')
```

It turns out that arg doesn't hold {'name1', 'name2'} at all but a bunch of system parameters. 
For loop yields nothing.

{
  0 : "/home/jun/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th"
  -2 : "-e"
  -5 : "/home/jun/torch/install/bin/luajit"
  -3 : "package.path="/home/jun/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/jun/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/home/jun/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/jun/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;"..package.path; package.cpath="/home/jun/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/home/jun/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;"..package.cpath"
  -4 : "-e"
  -1 : "local k,l,_=pcall(require,"luarocks.loader") _=k and l.add_context("trepl","scm-1")"
}

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`arg` doesn't work for function parameters in Lua 5.1+ (it could work in 5.1 with some compatibility options turned on; it only works for script parameters). You need to use `local arg = {...}` to assign function parameters to a table or use `select(i, ...)` to get i-th parameter from the list and `select('#', ...)` to get the number of parameters. The former is simpler, but the latter option can deal with `nil` values in the passed parameters, so use it if you expect `nil` values.